# Should we have some sort of GeoTag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Suppose someone is looking for questions relating to a particular location or region (e.g. [Texas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3918/geocode-from-mile-marker-milepost-to-latitude-longitude)).

Since this is a site devoted to GIS, maybe should support spatial queries.  I'm not sure what sort of tagging system we should use though.

Any ideas?

Here's [another example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/parameters-for-ed50-etrs89-wgs84-seven-parameter-transformation-which-are-good) of a post that might benefit from a geotag.  I'm reluctant to suggest having the name of the country as a tag, realizing that would ruffle many geo-feathers.

Another example - "[Where can I find China data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/where-can-i-find-china-data)"?

Maybe this question is both meta and non-meta.

From [an interesting NYTimes article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/02/07/technology/07question.html) that mentions Stack Exchange:

> Hipster, a mysterious start-up ... is
> said to tie questions to particular
> locations.

Anyone know anything about that?

I put my email in, but it says I need to refer 3 others before they let me in. http://usehipster.com/?referred_by=34493

Answer (score 3):

What would be the benefit of a geotag compared to a normal [keyword search for texas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=texas)? Adding geotags just sounds like more work to me, while Geohashes are a *lot* more work (how many can you type off the top of your head?).

Answer (score 1):

I was jokingly going to suggest [geohash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), but using actual geohashes as part of a tag, even at low precision, would be bad idea.  Then I thought about it some more.

Maybe use a geohash tag to signal that a geohash is present in the question or an answer to a question.  In the question/answer, put the actual geohash `geohash:dr5ru4rsv0jcy`.

For searching, users could enter:
`[geohash] dr5ru4rsv0jcy` or generalize the search by dropping characters off the end of the geohash: `[geohash] dr5ru4` (<strike>which should also return any precisely geohashed locations within the same bounding box</strike>).  **Update**: that doesn't work, the text searches match on word, not parts of word.  So this would only be useful from a Google search, not from within [gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com).

Using this system would inherit [geohash limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash#Limitations).  Another limitation would be no location information in the actual tag, thus preventing location-tagged RSS feeds. A third would be the extra step in converting a lat/long coordinate to geohash and back again--geohashes aren't easily human-readable (unless you work with them a lot).

Comment: I wonder if we could use tag synonyms to address the readability issue? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms

Comment: I don't see geohashes as having any useful value -- nothing beyond what already exists in coordinate systems or map references.

Answer (score 1):

I see some value in adding geotags at the higher levels like country, continent and planet but not at anything below country because it would mean that there are far too many of them.

By having questions tagged using a country, continent or planet name it enables GIS professionals familiar with that country, continent or planet to include them in their Watched Tags.

For example, I suspect an Australian GIS Professional not focussed on coordinate systems (and therefore not watching that tag) might often know enough about Australian datums like AGD66, AGD84, GDA94 and GDA2020 to be able to answer a question or recognize a duplicate  involving them if they are watching the [australia](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia) tag.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is realistic, but there could be an optional 'geotag' button, and when this is clicked an interactive world map comes up with several scales. Then once the users zooms to the appropriate level with a bounding box, and they choose their area of interest.